# Is it possible to use the boost library in a C++ DLL Project?

Tags: c++, boost, dll

I´m trying to use the boost Library example for a websocketserver (https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/beast/example/websocket/server/async/websocket_server_async.cpp) inside a DLL Project. I want to compile it into a single DLL.
It´s completely working inside a console Application, but if I move the code to my DLL Project I can´t even use the needed includes. This problem also appears on blank dll Projects with the same include configuration as the console app.
The include "boost/beast/core.hpp" failes with the following errors (all in the file "boost\beast\core\impl\file_stdio.ipp" in line 244):

- '(': illegal token on right side of '::'
- type 'unknown-type' unexpected
- syntax error: 'unknown-type' should be preceded by '('
- syntax error: ')'
- syntax error: missing ';' before '{'

I´m using the boost Version 1.72.0
I´ve got no idea what the difference between the console App and an DLL is.
Is it even possible to use the library properly for a DLL? If yes, do you have any ideas what I´m doing wrong?

Edit:
The code causing the error inside the boost library is the following:

```
if(offset > static_cast<std::uint64_t>(std::numeric_limits<long>::max()))
{
    ec = make_error_code(errc::invalid_seek);
    return;
}
```

especially the "::max()" causes the error

Comment: Please edit your question to show the code causing the problem as well as the error messages verbatim.  You might also want to provide the command you use to compile the code.

Comment: I´ve added the code of the library. To compile I use the default setup of the given Visual Studio Projects and just added \boost_1_27_0 and \boost_1_27_0\stage\lib to the include paths